# How to get text file data into table format using pandas in jupyter notebook?

Tags: text-files, pandas-datareader

I have a data like this in a text file

subject:
'math','science','physics','chemistry'
marks:
'75','62','92','90'

How to print this data in table fomat usingpandas in jupyternote book ?

Comment: Please share few lines of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just read all data and individually remove `'`, like so:

```
from io import StringIO
df_marks = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""'math','science','physics','chemistry'
'75','62','92','90'"""))

df_marks.columns = df_marks.columns.str.strip("'")

df_marks = df_marks.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("'"))
df_marks
```